# Как работает метод GetILAsByteArray()?

Tags: c#, .net, рефлексия

Метод `MethodBody.GetILAsByteArray();` возвращает IL-код в байтовом представлении, сие ясно. Однако я не нашел конкретики в описании работы данного метода на `MSDN`: возвращает ли он "*дословную*" инструкцию, которую описывал я, либо же эта функция возвращает именно ту инструкцию, которая будет исполняться?

Поясню:

- В **Debug**-режиме компилятор никак не оптимизирует код, так что
  исполняемая инструкция идентична той, которую описывал сам
  программист.
- В **Release**-режиме же компилятор инлайнит, упраздняет и в целом
  меняет многие вещи, так что конечная исполняемая инструкция может
  серьезно разниться с тем, что изначально описывалось.

---

**Влияет ли** как-то на `GetILAsByteArray()` режим компиляции, или же данный метод всегда возвращает "*дословную*" инструкцию метода?

Comment: Инлайнит не компилятор C#, а JIT,  который преобразует IL в машинный код. IL код лежит в сборке,  и в момент выполнения уже никак не меняется.

Comment: Понял, спасибо)

Comment: Т.е. не совсем понятно что вы подразумеваете под "что описал программист" и "конечной исполняемой инструкцией ". Программист пишет на c#, компилятор c# преобразует код в IL,  применяя оптимизации. IL - это байты в сборке. 
 Потом на конкретной платформе JIT преобразует IL в машинный код,  применяя свои оптимизации. Метод, про который вы спрашиваете, возвращает IL. Это и не "что написал программист", и не "то,  что будет реально выполнено". Это промежуточный результат на переносимом промежуточном языке :)

Comment: @PashaPash Спасибо, таки понял) Я почему-то раньше думал, что оптимизации применяются лишь на стадии IL-кода) Почему не как ответ?)

Comment: Коммент с телефона проще оформить :) :(

Comment: @PashaPash, но ведь для debug и release сборок будет разный il?

Comment: @Grundy да,  ес-но,  просто слово "идентична" тут неприменимо. IL будет соответствовать коду на c# и в debug, и в release,  просто с разным уровнем соответствия

Comment: @Grundy например, в простой метод с async/await компилятор столько своего добавит, что там debug и release друг на друга будут похожи,  а на исходный код на c# - нет.

Comment: @PashaPash, ну это уже другая история :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Влияет ли как-то на GetILAsByteArray() режим компиляции

Ответ - "да". В этом легко убедиться на практике. Напишем тестовый метод:

```
public void Method(int a, int b)
{    
    string str = (a+b).ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(str);
}
```

Далее, напишем такой код для извлечения первого операнда из его MSIL-кода и отображения имени операции:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

...

var mi = this.GetType().GetMethod("Method");
byte[] msil = mi.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray();
ushort op;

if(msil[0]==0xfe) 
    op = (ushort)(msil[1] | 0xfe00);
else 
    op = (ushort)(msil[0]);

//найдем имя операции
string str="";
FieldInfo[] mas = typeof(OpCodes).GetFields();
for(int i=0;i<mas.Length;i++)
{                
    if (mas[i].FieldType == typeof(OpCode))
    {
        OpCode opcode = (OpCode)mas[i].GetValue(null);
        if (opcode.Value == op)
        {
            str = opcode.ToString();
            break;
        }
    }
}

textBox1.Text = "0x"+op.ToString("X4")+": "+str;
```

**Результат:**

Debug - `0x0000: nop`

Release - `0x0003: ldarg.1`

Объясняется это тем, что в отладочной сборке в начале каждого метода вставляется пустой оператор для облегчения отладки (чтобы можно было поставить точку останова на самое начало метода, тогда как в релизной сборке можно только на первую строку). Таким образом, режим компиляции действительно влияет на IL-код метода.